# PayPal REST API check completed order

Tags: php, paypal

I got E-Commerce shop, and currently I am developing the Paypal Rest API. 
The whole logic goes like this:

1. Customer want to check out his products (checkout.php: Bunch of $_POST variables)
2. He can choose his delivery and billing address, and payment option
3. There are currently 2 Payment options: PayPal and Cash
4. After he selects his payment option (let’s assume he selected cash), he is submitting his form (order.php)
5. Order.php runs completeOrder() method, which saves all the $_POST data to the database. Such as, delivery address and so on

**Now comes the thing where I am stuck.**

Let’s assume that Customer selects PayPal payment method. Like I stated before, he submits his form (order.php), but now instead running completeOrder() method, it  redirect to PayPal, where he can cancel his Payment, and confirm. As soon as he confirms, is going to redirect to order.php.

Now what I want here, is to check if the Status is confirmed, and run completeOrder() only when its payed!

Now the problem is, when customer gets redirected to the PayPal page, **he looses all $_POST values**, and it can’t run completeOrder() anymore.

```
Warning: Undefined array key "payment" in /var/www/html/src/Services/CheckoutService.php on line 77

Warning: Undefined array key "cartid" in /var/www/html/src/Services/CheckoutService.php on line 104

Warning: Undefined array key "billingaddress" in /var/www/html/src/Services/CheckoutService.php on line 107

Warning: Undefined array key "deliveryaddress" in /var/www/html/src/Services/CheckoutService.php on line 108
```

Inside Paypal API I added as return url (after payment) order.php, and as cancel url cart.php

Order.php (Checkout Controller)

```
       $success = $this->checkoutService->completeOrder();

        if (isset($_SESSION['orderId'], $_GET['token'])) {
            $orderId = $_SESSION['orderId'];
            $accessToken = $this->paypal->getAccessToken();
            $token = $_GET['token'];
            $orderConfirm = $this->paypal->capturePayment($accessToken,$orderId,$token);
            if($orderConfirm['id'] === $token && $orderConfirm['status']==='COMPLETED'){
                $this->checkoutService->finishOrder();
                header('Location: success');
            }else { 
               header('Location: error');
            }
        }
```

Complete (Checkout Service.php)

```
    public function completeOrder(): bool
    {
        //Security reason: Line 83
        $cart = $this->cartService->getCart();

        //Payment method (Cash or PayPal)
        $payment = $_POST['payment'];

        //Extra security for checkout: getCart()
        if ($cart) {
            $totalPrice = $cart->getTotalprice();
            if ($payment === 'paypal') {
                $accessToken = $this->paypal->getAccessToken();
                $this->paypal->setOrderPrice($totalPrice);
                $this->paypal->cretePaypalOrder($accessToken);
            } else {
                $this->finishOrder();
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Finish Order (Checkout Service.php) -> Insert to Database

```
    public function finishOrder(): void
    {
        //Current Date
        $date = date('Y-m-j');

        //Customer, Cart ID
        $customerId = $_SESSION['customerId'];
        $cartId = $_POST['cartid'];

        //Billing, Delivery Address
        $billingAdress = $_POST['billingaddress'];
        $deliveryAddress = $_POST['deliveryaddress'];

        //Finish the order -> Update Cart
        $this->checkoutRepository->orderProducts($date, $customerId);

        //Insert Billing, and delivery Address
        $this->addressRepository->insertOrderedBillingAddress($cartId, $billingAdress);

        if ($deliveryAddress !== $billingAdress) {
            $this->addressRepository->insertOrderedDeliveryAddress($cartId, $deliveryAddress);
        } else {
            //Insert delivery address same to billing
            $this->addressRepository->insertSameAsBillingAddress($cartId, $billingAdress, $_POST['sameasbilling']);
        }


    }
```

TO SUM UP:
I want to make sure that the payment was completed. And if yes, than save to databse. If no, throw error.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Don't use any redirects. That is an old integration method, for old websites.

Instead follow the [PayPal Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order' (see the optional step 5 in 'Add and modify the code').  You can use the [Checkout-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK) for these API calls (not the deprecated PayPal-PHP-SDK). Both of the 2 routes should return/output only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you can store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding the JSON response to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with this frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Why is this old? I mean, I've made own PayPal Class, and went through REST API documentation? Checkout PHP SDK is not supported anymore? Because Documentation on PayPal don't exist anymore @PrestonPHX [PHP SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/setup-sdk/)

Comment: The PayPal-PHP-SDK is the one that is deprecated. From your code I have no idea what you are using but if it is the Checkout-PHP-SDK, fine. The important thing is that the v2/checkout/orders API is being used. Redirects are for old websites, no reason to use them. See the current integration pattern in the guide and demo linked above.